Discrepancy between cross-validation and test set accuracy
I'm working on a kaggle dataset called Spaceship Titanic, and currently having a problem that I'm really stuck.
For some reason, I cannot reliably use 5-fold cv accuracy as a representor of the test set accuracy. What I mean is, as an example, when I drop a particular feature from the dataset, my cv accuracy increases from 0.7923 to 0.8048. However, my test set accuracy decreases from 0.8026 to 0.7961. Similarly when I optimize my hyperparameters according to my cv accuracy, my test set accuracy drops.
What might be causing this discrepancy? Also is there any suggestions for me to perform validation in such a way that changes in its accuracy directly reflects to the test set, not necessarily magnitude wise but direction wise?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

How many significant digits do your performance estimates actually have? (What are the sample sizes?)

The problem is solved now :) Thanks for the reply. But I would like to still ask, is there a systematic way of calculating how many significant digits are there? It seems like a very helpful information. My current dataset has 8693 train and 4277 test samples.

For stability and efficiency run 100 repeats of 10-fold CV.

I will try, thanks. Is there a rule of thumb or something similar for this purpose?

Well, it seems the two situations I have described above were caused by different issues.
The one about discrepancy in feature's effect on accuracy was caused by an implementation error of mine. Right now cv and test set accuracies mostly agree.
However, problem with hyperparameter optimization was solved when I have introduced a separate validation set. In the previous setup, I have been calculating the out-of-train sample accuracies each time I want to calculate the accuracy of a given hyperparameter set, then choosing the set that gives the best accuracy. It seems this is extremely prone to overfitting. When I have separated another validation set (about %30 of the size of train set) and also calculated the accuracy on it, I have observed these hold-out accuracies are all over the place. Sometimes increasing sometimes decreasing. However choosing the hyperparameters set with the best hold-out accuracy resulted in a set of hyperparameters that were actually consistently improving both the validation set accuracy and the test set accuracy.
